# What happen if 95% of bees die?

Tags: biology, earth, life

Suppose that in 2 years due to a virus the percentage of bees decreased by 95%. How nature react to this change ? How would the man face the problem?

Comment: The virus is gone afterwards? They recently lost 44% apparently. https://beeinformed.org/2016/05/10/nations-beekeepers-lost-44-percent-of-bees-in-2015-16/ Bees, just like most insects, will multiply quickly and not that many people will even notice.

Comment: Scientist find a cure of the virus after 2 years !

Comment: [What if Bees went extinct?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izGQketQzTc)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. What you have done there is come up with a concept for building a world. But then you are asking **us** to do the work of actually building it for you; of figuring out what the actual consequences of this concept are. That is not what we do here.

Comment: Not too broad.  reasonable question.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I imagine a virus that (wait for it) *virulent* would go extinct as its hosts die back.  I do hope they unlock the question...

Comment: [Found this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kf2-86o5S1o). The TL;DW is that nature would actually be better off if honey bees were wiped out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bees are vital to so many crops. We need them to survive. However, as noted, we have lost a huge percentage of bees already, and no one has noticed. If it was that close to 100%, you'd see scientists getting involved. They'd have to cure the virus or breed bees that are not susceptible to it. Tiny nanomachine bees might be invented as well if the virus were incurable. They would have to find a solution though.
Any lower than 90% and I imagine the general public would not even notice.